# Laravel Greater than or equal in views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I passed a variable to view and I want to make an if condition for this value with greater than or equal

example

```
@if($var >= 3)
do something...
@endif
```

when I do this I got this error

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to int

I search a lot about this but I didn't get any answers

Comment: You are comparing `collection` instead of `int` value. Share your complete code

Comment: can you print_r($var)?

Comment: if it a collection of records and you want to compare its `count` you can edit it to `$var->count() > 3`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to compare the number of records. Then you can achieve the same as below

```
if ($var->count() >= 3){ }

if (count($var) >= 3) {}
```